# Is there a deep reason why strong estimates fail to exist for $L^1$ so often?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

For example, the Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality fails to have a strong type estimate in the $(1,1)$ case.

Another example is the Hilbert transform which has strong type $(p,p)$ bounds for $1<p<\infty$ but fails to be bounded on $L^1$.

Is there a deep reason why such estimates fail so often for $L^1$?

Comment: What do you mean that Fourier transform maps $L^1$ to a larger space than $L^1$? The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is always continuous. The natural reason to expect more regularity for $L^p$ with $p\in (1,\infty)$ in general should be that $L^1$ is not reflexive, whereas the other $L^p$ spaces are.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I am sorry, that was a false statement. I removed it. But why does reflexivity offer so much more regularity?

Comment: Start by looking at the unit ball in the $\ell^1$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Notice anything about the convexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I.** There is a clear reason why bounding Fourier multipliers in $L^1$ is more difficult that doing so in $L^p$, with $1 < p < \infty$. $L^1$ is an Abelian Banach algebra with respect to the convolution and that Banach algebra, although it doesn't have a unit, it admits uniformly $L^1$-bounded approximate units (think of mollifications of $\delta_0$). The space of bounded Fourier multipliers in $L^1$ is equal to the so-called space of multipliers of the algebra $M(L^1)$ given by:
$$ 
  M(A) = \big\{ T \in B(A) : T(a \ast b) = a \ast T(b) \big\}.
$$
If the algebra $A$ had a unit $1$, then $T(f \ast 1) = f \ast T(1)$ and $M(A) = A$. Of course $L^1$ doesn't have a unit. But, using tricks with approximate units, it is not difficult to show that this space is given by convolutions with finite measures, ie: $T(f) = \mu \ast f$. A proof can be found in [St].

Therefore an $L^1$-bounded Fourier multiplier $m$ has to satisfy that $\widehat{m}$ is a finite measure. A pretty difficult thing that the Hilbert transform $$\xi \mapsto -i \operatorname{sgn}(\xi)$$ doesn't satisfy since its transform grow logarithmically.

**II.** For the maximals I do not have an "easy" reason. In the case of the Hardy-Littlewood maximal, if it were bounded in $L^1$ the strong maximal, given by
$$
  M_{\mathrm{st}}(f) := \sup_{r,s > 0} \, \sup_{|I| = r, \, |J| = s} \,  \frac1{r \cdot s} \int_{I \times J} |f(z,w)| dz \, dw,
$$
where $I$, $J$ are intervals such that $(x,y) \in I \times J$, would be bounded in $L^1$ as well. But it's very easy to see that that can not be, it is easier that in one dimension.

**III.** Another reason may came from the following paper of Stein [St2], that proves that $\| M(f) \|_1$ is comparable to the $L \log L$-norm using a Fubini-type trick.

---

[St]:*Stein, Elias M.*, Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions, Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press. XIV, 287 p. (1970). [ZBL0207.13501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0207.13501).

[St2]: *Stein, Elias M.*, [**Note on the class $L \log L$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm-32-3-305-310), Stud. Math. 32, 305-310 (1969). [ZBL0182.47803](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0182.47803).

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of "it is easier that in one dimension"?

Comment: It fails in a stronger way. Just taking $f \geq 0$ close to a Dirac $\delta$ in the origin woould give you that its maximal is (approximately) constant along hyperbolas $xy = 1$. And so the region in which $M_{st}(f) > 1$ is of infinite measure.